UE niagara Execute Behavior
I am learning Niagara, and I move some particles based on the RGB values in a texture. This is how I read the texture into a Grid 2D. When I reset the NS_Component in the blueprint, it does not execute my Generic simulation stage again. However, when I use the Reset Button from the details panel, the NS does run my Generic simulation stage. How should I properly control the NS to run and stop within the blueprint?
enter image description hereenter image description hereenter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


When I set it to "Always," I can successfully perform this function in the blueprint, but when I switch it to "OnSimulationReset," calling ResetSystem() in the blueprint does not work as expected. Logically, I want to read the data only when the simulation starts and not repeatedly throughout the entire process.
